# Second function is not running in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two functions and I want to call one function after the first is completed.

I wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        FetchProducts('@Model.ProductId', function () {
            SimilarProducts('@Model.Class.Group.SectionId', '@Model.ProductId', '@TempData["Min"]', '@TempData["Max"]');
        });
    });
```

`FetchProducts` function runs an ajax call that will fill `TempData["Min"]` and `TempDate["Max"]` and returns a list of products.

`SimilarProducts` want to make another ajax request by min and max to get some similar products. `FetchProducts` is running properly but `SimilarProducts` is not running.

Whats the problem?

**Update**

This is `FetchProducts` function:

```
function FetchProducts(productId) {
    $.getJSON("/product/jsonproducts", { productId: productId }, function (data) {
        var i = 0;
        $(".section-items-details").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

And this is `SimilarProducts` function:

```
function SimilarProducts(sectionId,productId, minimum, maximum) {
    $.getJSON("/product/getsimilarproducts", { sectionId: sectionId, productId: productId, min: minimum, max: maximum }, function (data) {
        var i = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Need to show code for `FetchProducts`.  Is its 2nd argument being called when the function is done?

Comment: May be the AJAX request is failing so the function is not called.

Comment: @RichardSchneider The 2nd function should be run after the first is done.

Comment: @adirohan As I mentioned the first function is working properly.

Comment: As far as I can see, FetchProducts() takes only one argument but while calling it you are passing a second argument...

Comment: @adirohan Yes but the function is working properly yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh well, since your update I can tell you where is the error :)

So, talk about your 'FetchProducts' function :

```
function FetchProducts(productId) {
$.getJSON("/product/jsonproducts", { productId: productId }, function (data) {
    var i = 0;
    $(".section-items-details").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        ...
    }
});
```

}

As we can see, your 'FetchProducts' function only accept one argument, but in his call, you added an anonymous function.

In order to make it working properly, you shoud edit your 'FetchProducts' function like this :

```
function FetchProducts(productId, callback) {
    $.getJSON("/product/jsonproducts", { productId: productId }, function (data) {
        var i = 0;
        $(".section-items-details").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ...
        }
        ...
        // Everything is ok, let's call our callback function!
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) callback();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think `FetchProducts` will call `SimularProduction`.  `FetchProducts` does nothing with the 2nd argument.

```
function FetchProducts(productId, then) {
  $.getJSON("/product/jsonproducts", { productId: productId }, function (data) {
    var i = 0;
    $(".section-items-details").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        ...
    }
    then();
});
```

}

Comment: Agree, you should modify FetchProducts() so that it accepts a second argument as a function, and calls that function inside the AJAX response